# Test that the 'save' function fails when invalid data is passed. (Ruby Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a project that has the following validation criteria in the "project" model:

```
validates :project_name,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z\s_-]+\z/,
                      message: 'allows letters, spaces, underscores, and hyphens' }
  validates :jira_id,
            uniqueness: true,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: /\A[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\z/,
                      message: 'allows capitalized letters followed by a hyphen and numbers' }
  validates :capacity,
            presence: true,
            numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :openings,
            presence: true,
            numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validates_format_of :last_status_change_dt,
                      with: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,
                      message: 'must be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD',
                      on: :save

  validates_presence_of :last_status_change_dt
```

The projects_controller:

```
def create
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      parameters = project_params.dup
      parameters[:language_id] = get_language_id(params[:language_name]) if parameters[:language_id].nil?
      @project = Project.new(parameters)
      if @project.save
        render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project
      else
        render json: @project.errors, status: :not_acceptable
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
    render json: { text: 'Project was not created' }, status: :internal_server_error
  end
```

In the spec file, FactoryBot build and create functions are used.

In the tests right now, the validation is dependent on the project model, but I want to test the save function. How can I mock the save function to fail?

Comment: IMO it's better not to mock the save function ... instead, just introduce a validation error with your test data (e.g. give it a piece of invalid data) and then the `save` will fail as a result

Comment: `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` is a pretty generic and unusual error. Instead of rescuing it in individual controllers it might make more sense to rescue it at a higher level and issue a more generic error. Also, you shouldn't have to roll back if save returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance), but that's a bit of a hammer. Instead, make a double and mock Project.new to return it.

```
context 'Project#save raises ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError' do
  let(:project) {
    # Set up the double to fail on save.
    instance_double("Project").tap { |project|
      allow(project).to receive(:save).and_raise(ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError)
    }
  }

  before {
    # Set up Project.new to return the double
    allow(Project).to receive(:new).and_return(project)
  }
end
```

Note that it's quite unusual for `save` to raise ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, if it does something very unusual has gone wrong. You generally don't rescue it in a controller.

Comment: `save` doesn't raise an `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` in practice. It returns a boolean indicating whether the record was saved. You may have been thinking of `save!`. This is an example of how stubs can actually be harmful. In this case it's forcing the tests to do something that the code doesn't.

Comment: @maxpleaner I thought the same thing as you, initially. The OP appears to be wanting to test when the database catches fire. IMO I don't think they should be catching it in this controller. Either way, it's a useful pattern.

Comment: I joined this project a few weeks ago, and don't know Ruby. I'll relay this on to my supervisor, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Sugandha More specifically this is the Ruby On Rails framework (Ruby is the language). I'd recommend going through the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to get familiar.

Comment: I get where you're coming from @Schwern. Testing when the database catches fire is a reasonable thing to do. However it's usually handled differently - there will be a global error handler (usually provided by an error logging service, e.g. Bugsnag / New Relic / etc), and the client will receive a 500, showing a generic error message to the user. I've heard that it's a bad security practice to show specifics of unhandled errors to the end-user.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, I agree. The OP didn't ask about that, they asked how to test the exception, so that's the answer. The rest is what comments and side-notes are for. The "useful pattern" I referred to is how to test an exception from an internally created object; mock the constructor to return a double.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to examine the `response` object and see if the `json` errors are returned correctly, I typically do something like this:

```rb
context "when saving the project fails" do
  let(:params} do
    { 
      language_id: 123,
    }
  end
  let(:subject) { post :create, params: params }

  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(Project).to receive(:valid?) do |project|
      project.errors.add(:language_id, 'fake validation reason')
      false
    end
  end

  it 'should return an error response' do
    subject
    expect(response).to have_http_status(422)

    errors = response.parsed_body['errors']
    expect(errors).to be_present
    expect(errors['language_id']).to include 'fake validation reason'
  end
end
```

You can also re-write the above code with `instance_double`.